# Creating cells in excel showing Username and Password tabs like that in Fb

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting, vba

I want to create cells same like that of Username and Password tabs in fb or gmail. The cells must show the values to be entered in that cell i.e. "Enter username here" and "Enter Password here". As i click on it, the text in that cell i.e. "Enter Username here"  in it must get invisible. If i clear the text i entered, it should again show "Enter username here". Please suggest how can i create such cells in Excel.

I don't want to save credentials. Actually i have created multiple drop down lists in my sheet. And people are not getting to see that there is a dropdown list in that cell until then they click on it. So i want to show these way so that they can get to know that there is a droodown list in that cell. I know i can add comment but i want to show these way so it can look more good.

I want cells which will show "Enter Username here" in lightish colour, and as i enter in that cell to enter anything the"Enter Username here"must disappear. If i clear the contents i entered, the "Enter Username here" must again get visible.

Comment: You could use the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel) event for this. But why do you want to store credentials this way in a spreadsheet?

Comment: I don't want to save credentials. Actually i have created multiple drop down lists in my sheet. And people are not getting to see that there is a dropdown list in that cell until then they click on it. So i want to show them these that you have to select these data here, that data there. I know i can add comment but i want to show these way so it can look more good.

Comment: ***"Welcome to [so]!"***  You might have the wrong idea about this site; it's a place for programmers to give/get help when a solution to a problem can't be found elsewhere. The best questions include code samples, but any ***specific,*** practical, answerable programming problem is welcome . Please see the [tour] as well as "[help/on-topic]" and also "[ask]". Also there's good tips [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question) and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mask the characters by setting a **Custom Number Format** of:

## **`;;;**`**

[image: pic]

Comment: Thanks ashleedawg, but I don't want such cells. I want cells which will show "Enter Username here" in lightish colour, and as i enter in that cell to enter anything the"Enter Username here"must disappear. If i clear the contents i entered, the "Enter Username here" must again get visible.

Answer (score 1):

***I wouldn't recommend storing passwords this way***, but there is a simple way to create this 'effect' with simple formatting..

Let's say the Username is in cell `D4` and Password is in `D5`.

Format the cells such that the font colour and background colour match. Any data entered into it is invisible to the casual viewer.

As for pre-populating the cells with "Enter Username/Password here" - enter the text in the cell to the left, i.e. `C4` and `C5`. Then set the column width of column `C:C` to 1.

This will cause the text to appear if `D4` or `D5` are empty as the text will 'overflow' across those cells.

Comment: https://youtu.be/CScEzzEhwVs i have watched the video in which they showed it very well. I am not getting how to use it in realtime.

Comment: Sorry omprakash, I can't view YouTube here.

Comment: Thanks CLR, the overflow technique is very helpful but there are many dropdown lists and i can't insert a column before every  dropdownlist. Is there any other way